# Why is the canonical projection Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $A=\{w:[0,\infty)->\mathbb{R}^d, \ w\text{ is continuous and } w(0)=0\}$, and let's use this metric of locally uniform convergence:

$\rho(w,v)=\sum_{n\geq 1} (1\wedge \sup_{i\in [0,n]}|w(i)-v(i)|)2^{-n} $.

Let also $\pi_t(w):=w(t)$(canonical projection).

Is the $\pi_t$ Lipschitz? Why?

I'm reading, Brownian Motion by Schlling and Partzsch, and they state that it is, without any proof. I've tried, but couldn't, and in fact I'm convinced it's not. Maybe they were thinking of Locally Lipschitz?

Comment: What is $t$? An integer? Same question for $i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's certainly not globally Lipschitz, since $\rho(w,v)\le 1$ always, but $\pi_t$ is unbounded.  Yes, I suspect they mean locally Lipschitz.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3085502/canonical-projection-on-the-set-of-continuous-functions-that-equal-0-at-x-0/3096293#3096293  Robert, I wrote an answer to a question equal to this. In my answer I try to prove that's it's locally lipschitz. Could you please check if it's ok? I hope I'm not being bothersome. ;)

Comment: Also, Thanks for your answer. =D ;)